# how to count the png files in windows page by using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

how to count the png files in windows page by using selenium webdriver

http://www.thefind.com/search?query=camera

go to above website and count the number of camera present in page by using seleniumwebdriver program

```
            driver.get("http://www.thefind.com/search?query=camera");
    List<WebElement> wb=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    System.out.println(wb.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the locator strategy. By short investigation of the page I realised that all camera are in same class with name `tf_search_item_productimage`

So change this line

```
List<WebElement> wb=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

to

```
List<WebElement> wb=driver.findElements(By.className("tf_search_item_productimage"));
```

And it should do the trick